# Why is bootstrap form and pannel overlapping?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I have a div panel and after it a form, and I have this same structured element twice. The form and the panel dive after it are overlapping. Here is my html:

```
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                user1
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                test comment
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <ul class="list-inline">

                    <li id="reply"><a href="#">reply</a></li>
                    <li id="expand"><a href="#"> expand</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="form col-xs-4" id="commentForm" action="comment.php" method="post" style="display:"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment"></textarea> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                user 2
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                test comment
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li id="reply"><a href="#">reply</a></li>
                    <li id="expand"><a href="#"> expand</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="form col-xs-4" id="commentForm" action="comment.php" method="post" style="display:"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment"></textarea> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5da7qeq/3/) is a fiddle to see what I mean by overlapping

I want the the width of the form to be limited, that is why i put `class="form col-xs-4"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `class="row"` before use bootstrap `col-*-*` class

your code like

```
<div id="comment">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            user1
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            test comment
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <ul class="list-inline">

                <li id="reply"><a href="#">reply</a></li>
                <li id="expand"><a href="#"> expand</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form col-xs-4" id="commentForm" action="comment.php" method="post" style="display:"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment"></textarea> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div> 
<div id="comment">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            user 2
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            test comment
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li id="reply"><a href="#">reply</a></li>
                <li id="expand"><a href="#"> expand</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form col-xs-4" id="commentForm" action="comment.php" method="post" style="display:"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment"></textarea> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

your form is not in the right div. You put it after the footer of the first panel and before the following panel.

This solves it :

```
<div id="main">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    user1
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form col-xs-4" id="commentForm" action="comment.php" method="post" style="display:"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" /> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment"></textarea> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
                </div>
            </form>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <ul class="list-inline">

                        <li id="reply"><a href="#">reply</a></li>
                        <li id="expand"><a href="#"> expand</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="comment">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    user 2
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form col-xs-4" id="commentForm" action="comment.php" method="post" style="display:"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" /> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment"></textarea> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
                </div>
            </form>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li id="reply"><a href="#">reply</a></li>
                        <li id="expand"><a href="#"> expand</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Be also careful, you had several div with the same id and this is not viable.

Comment: but I need two forms, one for each comment. I have two comments, one with a name of user 1 and with a name of user 2. and I want one reply form for each of those comments

Comment: Thanks about noting the same ids

Comment: just add the form in you panel-body <div>

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c2yr6b00/) is your code. That's not what I meant. Sorry if i was unclear. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/2p8qqpjm/) is what I meant. using @kapil's answer

Comment: glad you found your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please see Updated code.
https://jsfiddle.net/v5da7qeq/2/
Hope this will work !

Answer (score 0):

If you opt for a full width form layout you can just remove the **col-xs-4** class from your forms.

```
<form class="form" id="commentForm" action="comment.php" method="post" style="display:">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Neviton/v5da7qeq/4/

Comment: ah, thanks but I don't want a full width form layout.